# Last Access Time isn't updated when a file is opened from the search view

Tags: windows-10

DisableLastAccess is Disabled. That is, last access is not disabled:

```
fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess
DisableLastAccess = 0  (User Managed, Disabled)
```

Comment: Have you restarted? A restart is required if you change this value ...

Comment: I actually did try to restart, however I didn't even change the value, just check it.